# How do I install Mercurial from source on Fedora 8

Tags: fedora, mercurial

I have a installed Fedora 8 on AWS. Currently it has Mercurial 1.1 running on it.
However I need to upgrade Mercurial to be at least version 1.7.5 (or above).

Can I compile latest Mercurial on Fedora 8 and will it work?

Comment: Might be time to update fedora

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [installation instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall) in our wiki. Basically you need to install the `python-devel` package first, grab the source code and then do

```
$ make local
$ ln -s $PWD/hg ~/bin/hg
```

to put a symlink for the `hg` script into `~/bin` — which I hope is a directory on your `PATH`.